# How to boot an image with no information

Tags: encryption, linux, virtualization

I am investigating the security of a system that I bought.
To update it a .img file is used. Now I am wondering if that is really safe.
I used fdisk -l to get information about the image. I get only this Information:

```
933.75 MiB, 979107840 bytes, 1912320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

When I unzip it there is an file called **image_** and another **file meta_**
Both seem to be binary files.
I tried to boot it with `qemu-system-x86_64 my.img`
Has anybody an idea how I could get the information or how I could find out if the .img is encrypted?

Thanks for help

Comment: try with `file qemu-system-x86_64 my.img`

Comment: A System? Like a PC? Or what? And who's image file is that then? Can you not just nuke what's on the system an install an OS of your choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `binwalk` to extract the contents of the image. It can extract the file system and you can mount it to inspect the files.

This is how security researchers inspect firmware files without having the physical device in hand.